# Google Calendars OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I' m trying to use Google calendars API.
It takes to authorized via OAuth2. I copied code from [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/python?hl=en)
But it returns 400 *redirect_uri_mismatch*
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cLjr.png)
In my  credentials I have redirect URI:
[credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c32Tk.png)
Also there is item `"redirect_uris":["http://localhost:8080"]` in credentials.json
How can I fix my problem?

I tryed to add `flow.redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8080'` to my script but it doesnt help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the javascript sdk, and set the redirect_uri=postmessage
it's the most suitable way to do this
( set this in your backend as well)

and in your google app, add  localhost:port to the authorized origins,
in your case: add http://localhost:8080